# Next.js—unable to set up proxy

Tags: next.js, proxy, localhost, storyblok

I am trying to make a blog using Storyblok(v2) and Next.js(v13). I've gone through this exact tutorial before, and I was able to get the proxy up and running multiple times. [Here](https://www.storyblok.com/tp/add-a-headless-cms-to-next-js-in-5-minutes) is the tutorial for the blog, and [here](https://www.storyblok.com/faq/setup-dev-server-https-proxy) is what I've been using to set up my proxy (on macOS).

The last time that I went through this tutorial, I was using the same versions of Storyblok and Next. I have no problem at all running those commands re: setting up the proxy, and my terminal does say that it's up and running, `https://localhost:3010 -> http://localhost:3000`.

When I visit both `https://localhost:3010` and `http://localhost:3000`, I get `Error: {"message":{}, "status":401, "response":"Unauthorized"}`.

Before I created the proxy, everything was working as expected, so I believe that the errors are definitely related to the proxy. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your storyblok API token is correct. That looks like an error related to that...